# Image Processing with Matlab

Tags: matlab

Today I'm learning most of the rules in matlab and need help to make this function get the maximum and minimum of each color

```
 function [mini,maxi] = min_max(imageName)
ima = imread(imageName);
imshow(ima);
ima = rgb2gray(ima);
imagesc(ima);
axis image;
mini = min(min(ima));
maxi = max(max(ima));
```

when I using this picture

```
[mini,maxi]=min_max('peppers.png');
```

![I see this pic][1]

please help me
:'(

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any pictures in your post, but I think your question is:

"Why am I getting this picture
[image]

instead of this"

[image]

The reason is because you haven't specified a `colormap` and `imagesc` defaults to the `jet` colormap. To get a grayscale image, use `colormap(gray)` after the `imagesc` line

Secondly, as a general tip, if you want to find the `min` or `max` value in the entire matrix, instead of calling it twice, use `min(ima(:))` and `max(ima(:))`. This will give you the same answer and is much faster when your matrix size is large and/or when you use it repeatedly in loops.